# SQL, how to get the automated ID from the previous INSERT?

Tags: php, sql, insert, auto-increment

I am using `PHP` and `SQL` and trying to insert user data into two tables upon registration. First in the `user_table` and second into the `character_table`. I'm using an automatically generating `user_id` to link the tables and need to get the value of the `user_id` from the first `INSERT (into user_table)` then add it to a column in the `character_table`.

I tried a few methods and here is where I ended ($username, $email, $password and $character are defined above);

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
user_table (id, username, email, password)
VALUES ('NULL', '".$username."', '".$email."', '".$password."')

INSERT INTO
character_table (name, id)
VALUES ('".$character."', 'LAST_INSERT_ID()')";"
```

I want "id" from user_table to match with "id" inserted into character_table.

When I run the above, nothing seems to be happening. Previous attempts I always ended with id = 0. What is the correct way I can get the ID from the first INSERT?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: are you ready for your db to be attacked and possibly deleted? you may get a rude awakening one day, maybe that will open your eyes to sql injection prevention methods.

Comment: nothing happens because you're trying to run a multi query, but that may not be the case since we don't know how your executing that query

Comment: Please add additional scope of your code on how you are executing the query. Good luck!

Comment: *"nothing seems to be happening"* - Nothing at all?  Or perhaps *something that you're not observing*?  If "nothing" is happening then this code doesn't even execute, which means the problem is elsewhere.  (Casual observations: (1) This code has a syntax error at the very end. (2) Even if this code executes, all it does is define a string variable.  Nothing more.  (3) If you *are* executing this SQL code, it's wide open to SQL injection.  (4) I *really* hope you're not storing user passwords in plain or decryptable text.

Comment: @fred-ii No need to be so rude, it's not very helpful if you aren't specific. I am still learning.

I did run it as two separate queries and it seems to be working, yey.

Comment: @David passwords are hashed and defined in code above. If there is a resource you can share, I'm interested in reviewing.

Comment: *"No need to be so rude, it's not very helpful if you aren't specific."* - what in the world are you insinuating?? fk me, it's your database, do what the heck you want but don't come crying to us later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run your statements seperately. You run your insertion into your `user_table`, then grab the `id` then run your insertion into your `character_table`
2. You can grab the `id` using `mysql_insert_id` after running the insert. [Note that on the php webpage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) detailing the `mysql_insert_id` function that it is deprecated as is all `mysql*` functions. Which leads to...
3. For the love of everything holy don't concatenate your variables directly to your INSERT statement. Switch to mysqli* functions or PDO if you haven't already and use prepared statements (parameterizing the query). If you build an application using `mysql` it means you are not parameterizing your queries which means you are at a huge risk for a sql injection attack.

If/when you switch over to mysqli or PDO functions you will find an equivalent `mysqli_insert_id()` (or `PDO::lastInsertID()`) function

Comment: Thank you, this works! Running separate statements has fixed the issue and it now works as I was hoping. Was I mixing mysql and mysqli? I didn't notice? I am using mysqli on all other areas of my code.

Comment: Oh! About the `mysql*` functions, you actually didn't specify and I was totally jumping to conclusions based on other's comments. My bad. That said, you aren't parameterizing your INSERT statement, so you are just as wide open to attack as if you were using solely `mysql` functions. [check out this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to see how to bind parameters (using "prepared statements") to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize. Thanks again, I will definitely read through that.